# Searching videos by category id

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I am using the Youtube v3 api, and I got all the categories id by using this call.

```
$videoCategories = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=us&key=xxxx');
```

Now I want to get top 5 videos from US on category 4 (Music).

What is the correct url syntax? And also how can I write a search array to it using the Youtube api instance?

Example:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
    'type' => 'video',
    // 'q' => $_GET['q'],
    'location' =>  'us',
    'maxResults' => 20,
));
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I implemented,this may be helpful.The `videoCategoryID` for music is `10`. You can see this here:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=10&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
So you code ends up looking like this:

```
$searchResponse = $youtube->search->listSearch('id,snippet', array(
    'q' => $_GET['q'],
    'maxResults' => $_GET['maxResults'],
    'type' => 'video',
    'videoCategoryId' => '10'
));
```

Here is a quick way to get the full list of categories:

```
<?php

$ids = implode(",", range(1,50));

$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&id=" . $ids . "&key={YOUR-API-KEY}");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);

foreach ($json_data['items'] as $category) {
    echo $category['id'] . ' = ' . $category['snippet']['title'] . '<br/>';
}

?>
```